# Running Hyper-V on Windows 11 Pro in Oracle Virtual Box on Windows Server 2019

Tags: virtualbox

I seem not to be able to get Hyper-V installed on my VM instance, and I need Hyper-V to be able to develop a Maui application in Visual Studio and the [Android emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/).

I am running Oracle Virtual Box 7.0.12 (latest) on a Windows 2019 Server (latest service pack), with a guest OS of Windows 11 Pro, and I seem not to be able to get the hyper-visor enabled on my VM.

- When I hover over the disabled hypervisor, it states there is no SLAT [Second Level Address Translation]; however, my host states it's ok and Virtualbox is configured with it

  ```
  systeminfo

    Hyper-V Requirements:  VM Monitor Mode Extensions:             Yes
                           Virtualization Enabled In Firmware:     Yes
                           Second Level Address Translation:       Yes
                           Data Execution Prevention Available:    Yes
  ```

**What have I done till now for my VM:**

1. **Host machine:** `--nested-hw-virt on` should enable hypervisor on my development PC

   ```
    VBoxManage modifyvm "Developer"
   ```
2. **VM settings:**

   - **Motherboard:** 
      [image: Motherboard]
   - **Processor:** 
      [image: Processor]
   - **Acceleration:** 
      [image: Acceleration]
3. **Within the VM:** 
   [image: Windows Hypervisor is disabled]

   - When I install a Quick-add VM in Hyper-V Manager, I start it, and it fails
   - Event Viewer has:

     ```
     Hypervisor launch failed; Second Level Address Translation is required to launch the hypervisor.
     ```

     ```xml
     <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
     <System>
       <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-Hypervisor" Guid="{52fc89f8-995e-434c-a91e-199986449890}" />
       <EventID>59</EventID>
       <Version>0</Version>
       <Level>2</Level>
       <Task>0</Task>
       <Opcode>0</Opcode>
       <Keywords>0x8000400000000000</Keywords>
       <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-11-30T03:55:47.8606482Z" />
       <EventRecordID>13096</EventRecordID>
       <Correlation ActivityID="{ee5ba102-fbae-4726-be84-d16b1df930dd}" />
       <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="8" />
       <Channel>System</Channel>
       <Computer>Developer</Computer>
       <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />
     </System>
     <EventData />
     </Event>
     ```

Comment: It might work better with a Hyper-V VM.

Comment: Have you tried to run a DISM command to enable the feature, and if so, what error message did you receive. Your screenshot shows Hyper-V is disabled on the guest OS.

Comment: @Ramhound, can you explain what you like to do with DISM? When use powershell to install all Hyper-V the services fails to start.

Comment: How you enable Windows features from PowerShell is well documented. You will have to provide more details about what happened when you attempted to enable Hyper-V because it’s show as disabled which is the default expected state until it’s enabled.

Comment: @Ramhound, my event log states: Hypervisor launch failed; Second Level Address Translation is required to launch the hypervisor.

Comment: Hyper-V only supports nesting inside Hyper-V VMs.. Hyper-V VMs also only supports nested Hyper-V. Everything else is not supported by Microsoft and may not work.

Comment: You can do what you need with Hyper-V and do not really need Virtual Box. Avoid nesting if you can (and you can with some reasonable thought).

Comment: @john, I need Virtual Box for my Windows driver development to debug native Windows drivers ... guess I need a 2nd PC

Comment: You can run VMware Workstation (newest) alongside of Hyper-V (not nested) and VMware can do all that VBOX does.

Comment: @WalterVehoeven - [Edit] your question with that relevant information. In [2021](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=95302) SLAT pass-through was not supported, I have no idea if it's supported in 2023 but it does not appear that is the case.  **You will have to use a different hypervisor other than VirtualBox**  If you want to run VirtualBox, within a VirtualBox VM, you can do that instead.  You wil be unable to enable Hyper-V within a VirtualBox VM.

Answer (score 1):

> I seem not to be able to get Hyper-V installed on my VM instance, and
> I need Hyper-V to be able to develop a Maui application in Visual
> Studio and the Android emulator.
>
> I am running Oracle Virtual Box 7.0.12 (latest) on a Windows 2019
> Server (latest service pack), with a guest OS of Windows 11 Pro, and I
> seem not to be able to get the hyper-visor enabled on my VM.

As of [2021](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=95302) SLAT pass-through was not supported.  This mean it's not possible to enable Hyper-V within a VirtualBox VM.

You will have to use a different hypervisor other than VirtualBox, if you want to enable Hyper-V, within a virtual machine.  You can of course run VirtualBox within a VirtualBox VM.

You will be unable to enable Hyper-V within a VirtualBox VM.